# Relationship between tangent normal of parametric curve and range of parameter

Tags: vector-analysis, parametric, parametrization

It is intuitive that by the right-hand rule one can choose direction of motion along a parametric curve by selecting one of the unit normal vectors. However, the relationship to the parameter is less clear. Is the direction defined by the range of values of the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean. For a parametric, regular (tangent vector is never $0$) and infinitely differentiable curve $\alpha: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, at each $t \in I$ one usually defines the unit tangent vector as $T(t) = \dfrac{\alpha'(t)}{\vert \vert \alpha'(t) \vert \vert} = (f'(t), g'(t))$. Out of convenience, the unit normal vector is $N(t) = (-g'(t), f'(t))$ (the choice is made like this so that $T$ and $N$ form a positively oriented orthonormal basis - also notice that this just means to take $T$ and rotate it $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ counter clockwise). The direction of the normal vector at each $t \in I$ is indeed dependent on the parameter $t$.

Comment: But, how can this be true if the parameter is increasing in some direction? If  The parameter has a direction of increase, T(t) has a direction and only one unit vector orthogonal to T is valid, not both.

Comment: Valid in what sense? The choice that I mentioned is made purely out of convenience (as I said, in order to form a positively oriented orthonormal basis). Yes, for any unit vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ there are two orthogonal unit vectors to $v$, but only one pair of them forms a positively oriented orthonormal basis. Think of the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: OK, I think I see. I may need to rephrase my question. Let's say I want a positive orientation (sorry, I'm not at the point yet where I understand the terminology "orthonormal basis"). How should I choose the parameter or the parameter range?

Comment: Basis means a set of vectors that can generate (i.e any other vector in that space will be a combination of the vectors in that set) some space. Orthonormal means that all the vectors in that set have length one. Positively oriented means that when you put the two vectors in the column of a matrix, the determinant of that matrix is positive. Lastly, your parameter range depends on what curve you were given: I'll explicate a little more on my next comment.

Comment: Say you were given the curve $\alpha(t) = (t, t^2) \ \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $T(t) = \dfrac{(1, 2t)}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}$, and $N(t) = \dfrac{(-2t,1)}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}}$. Notice that, as I said before, at every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (this is not always the case - you could have a curve that is defined only in some interval of $\mathbb{R}$) the vectors $T$ and $N$ form a positively oriented orthonormal basis.

Comment: In other words, T will allways be pi/2 CCW of N. But, how can I define the relationship between the parameter and the direction of N and T? I think my mistake was bringing in the right hand rule.

Comment: The relationship between the parameter and the direction of $N$ and $T$ depends on the curve. In general you define it just like I said. $T(t) = \dfrac{\alpha'(t)}{\vert \vert \alpha'(t) \vert \vert}$ and $N(t)$ is just $T$ rotated by $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise. That's the most information you're going to get for that relationship for any given curve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78009/discussion-between-joe-stavitsky-and-matheus-andrade).